# add_block sets gcb incorrectly when adding a Environment Controller block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a script to create a simulink model. I open a new model:

```
Trial>> new_system('newmodel')
Trial>> open_system('newmodel');
```

And add a new block (based on the example in the help documentation)

```
Trial>> gcb    
ans =
         ''       
Trial>> add_block('built-in/SubSystem', 'newmodel/Controller')
Trial>> gcb    
ans =    
newmodel/Controller
```

Note how gcb has been set to the expected value.

However, if i add a different block - this time an Environment Controller:

```
Trial>> add_block('Simulink/Signal Routing/Environment Controller', 'newmodel/envblock' )
Trial>> gcb    
ans =  
simulink/User-Defined Functions
```

For some reason, gcb is now pointing at `simulink/User-Defined Functions`. Which doesn't make any sense to me. This is neither the source nor destination block. What is going on?

Further, if i try and repeat the first command (that worked):

```
Trial>>  add_block('built-in/SubSystem', 'newmodel/Controller2')
Trial>> gcb

ans =

simulink/User-Defined
Functions
```

This one also points at the wrong place.

I can sort of resolve this by doing an explicit `load_system` / `open_system` prior to the `add_block`, but I don't really want to do that as it is just applying a band aid.

I need gcb to be pointing at the correct place, as I then go on to resize, create masks etc.

So:

1. Why is gcb not pointing at the correct block?
2. Is there a means of selecting an explicit block (either by handle or name) such that gcb is correctly pointing at it?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do `add_block` prior to doing `load_system` or manually loading/opening the library in the Simulink library browser. Not sure why `gcb` isn't pointing at the correct block. Normally it should return the path of the selected block.

Comment: As I understand it load_system and open_system differ only in that one opens it visibly. My expectation is also that gcb returns the to the selected block, which should be the block i just added. Rather frustratingly, it was working perfectly earlier.... I turned my back for two minutes...

Comment: Ah, it appears i need to run `simulink;` first to open the library browser.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say. Or if you don't want to open the library browser, you can use `load_system` for the library in question prior to using `add_block`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to just load the library using load_system, but in any case forcing the load of the library browser solves my issue.